# Could an antimatter-dominated end of universe fix CPT?

Tags: cosmology, antimatter, cpt-symmetry, cpt-violation

My question is about the apparent CPT violation of the observed universe, due to the imbalance of matter and antimatter, but first I have a motivating observation:

General relativity respects time reversal (T) symmetry.  However, formation of black holes ostensibly spoil T symmetry, because a black hole cannot un-form.  What preserves T symmetry in this case is that if you evolve the system which formed the black hole *backwards* in time, you get a white hole singularity, which is the time-reversal of the black hole.  (We usually don't think about white holes because they aren't observed, presumably due to initial conditions of the universe.)

Now I wonder if something analogous can fix the observed CPT asymmetry: Is there a reasonable way in which antimatter could come to dominate at the end of the universe, as a CPT analog of the matter domination of the current "early" phase of the universe?

Comment: A symmetric theory can have spontaneously broken non-symmetric solutions. General relativity isn't particularly special in that respect and one does not have to be desperate about finding non-physical solutions that keep thinks symmetric looking. Time reversal invariance is simply not the normal state of nature. Humpty Dumpty, once broken, will stay broken.